# Bayesian multivariate regression with common coefficients

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, metropolis-hastings, gibbs

In a hierarchical model I'm working on, I have $K$ different $N\times P$ predictor matrices, each denoted $X_k$ and $K$ length $N$ outcome vectors each denoted $y_k$. Essentially, I have a multivariate regression problem, but I want to use one set of coefficients for all outcomes and all covariates.

$$
y_k \sim N_N(X_k\beta, \Sigma_k)
$$

Fitting one of these models is straightforward in a Bayesian setting.
Assuming $\beta \sim N_P(m, V)$,
the posterior is closed form, because

$$
\pi(\beta|X_k,y_k,\Sigma_k) = \pi(\beta) \pi(y_k | X_k,\beta,\Sigma_k) \\
        \propto 
        \exp \left(
            (\beta - m)'V^{-1}(\beta - m) + 
            (y_k - X_k\beta)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(y_k - X_k\beta)
        \right)
$$
followed by completing the square, etc, as in (eg) [the wiki page on the topic of Bayesian linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression). I'm ignoring

When fitting one set of coefficients $\beta$ to the entire set $X$ of the predictor matrices $X_k$ and the entire set $Y$ of the outcome vectors $y_k$, the posterior is of the form

$$
\pi(\beta|X,Y,\Sigma_k) = \pi(\beta)\prod_{k=1}^K \pi(y_k | X_k,\beta,\Sigma_k) \\
        \propto 
        \exp \left(
            (\beta - m)'V^{-1}(\beta - m) + 
            \sum_{k=1}^m(y_k - X_k\beta)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(y_k - X_k\beta)
        \right)
$$

Is it likely this can be expressed in closed form in a similar manner? To infer the actual model I could of course use a Metropolis-Hastings step, but I'm interested if there's a known closed form or obvious solution to this, as I find MH sampling can be inefficient for these cases.

Apologies if it's something obvious, I'm rather tired.

Comment: There are two ways to tackle this. One would be to combine the matrices and vectors, since it's basically just one regression. I don't want to do this because of data structure and modelling reasons. The second is to work through the equation above. Short answer is that it's absolutely straightforward; you just end up with a bunch of $\sum_{k=1}^K$ elements mixed in with the normal closed form update for $\beta$. You also can't use a joint normal-inverse gamma for $p(\beta,\sigma^2)$, but independent priors work fine.

Comment: I will try to write the actual conditionals up in a generic way on the off chance anybody is interested, though